# .Net Redirect to User Details after Login / passing the GUID of a User

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, guid

I am using MVC 3 .Net membership.  It's very new to me, and I'm stuck at redirecting the user to their user details page once they have successfully logged in.  Here's the Logon Controller.  My User details action is expecting the GUID of the User to be passed to it, and I don't know how to do that.  I've tried User.id? and Membershipt.GetUser() etc etc but I can't seem to get the GUID of the user that the User Details action needs.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", "User", new { id = User.??????});
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: It's not necessarily a Guid, but your looking for MembershipUser.PoviderUserKey http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey.aspx

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me - but when I try to access the Provider UserKey in this context it is not available.  Any other Ideas?

Comment: Thanks Asawyer - you put me in the right direction with ProviderUserKey  I solved it with  Object guid = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey; and then passed guid to the RedirecttoAction.

Answer (score 0):

All I find with a quick search is problems, rather than solutions or examples. While this doesn't mean anything in and of itself--I'm not familiar with the "AccountModel" and "LogOnModel" namespaces and the related methods. But I could still possibly help.

First question: Where is the GUID stored? Are you using a directory (AD/LDAP) or a database (SQL). The GUID is "in there", and if it is already accessible, wouldn't it be something like model.GUID. Your ValidateUser found the username, but it doesn't "know anything" about the GUID. 
ADODB, Linq, and DirectorySearcher all have relatively simple ways of fetching a GUID when you've got a valid username and password, for example.